# Different scales in psychological testing -- z score or other standardization ? within anova using repetead measures

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, z-score

I'm pretty sure this is a basic statistics question; however, here it goes: In psychological testing, let's assume some participants were tested with three different tests. The first goes from 1 to 10, the second goes from 1 to 100 and the third goes from 10 to 20. As the scales are different, higher means don't reflect higher performance.

I would like to check whether the mean results obtained are statistically different. I was prone to Z-score each column before comparing them, but I would like if other suggestion is advisable.

If you are a R user, just copy paste the code below

```r
#packages
library(tidyverse)
library(MCMCglmm)
#> Warning: package 'MCMCglmm' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> Carregando pacotes exigidos: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack
#> Carregando pacotes exigidos: coda
#> Carregando pacotes exigidos: ape
#> Warning: package 'ape' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ape'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     where
library(rstatix)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rstatix'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggpubr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpubr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ape':
#> 
#>     rotate

#fake data
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  participant = paste("subject",c(1:100)),
  test1 = rtnorm(n = 100, mean = 5, sd = 1, lower = 0, upper = 10), 
  test2 = rtnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 1, lower = 10, upper = 100), 
  test3 = rtnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = 1, lower = 10, upper = 20))

#long format
df_long = df %>%
  pivot_longer(-participant)

#plot
ggboxplot(df_long, x = "name", y = "value", add = "point")
```

[image]

```r
# hypothesis testing
res.aov <- anova_test(data = df_long, dv = value, wid = participant, within = name)
rstatix::get_anova_table(res.aov)
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#>   Effect  DFn    DFd        F         p p<.05   ges
#> 1   name 1.57 155.41 98773.37 2.78e-234     * 0.999
pwc <- df_long %>%
  pairwise_t_test(
    value ~ name, paired = TRUE,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What do you think would happen with the three means after transforming each test to z-scores?

Comment: The values will remain the same, but with mu = 0 and sd =1 . Why ?

Comment: The values change too, will roughly lie between -3 and +3. You can find ways to transform your scales here on CV. E.g. for transforming 7 point scales to 5 point scales. After transforming the 1-20 and 1-100 to a 1-10 scale, you could compare the means. So, forget the z-scores.